# Kibana Lens - Cannot cutomize timestamp on several months, weeks or years

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

I am creating a Lens Visualization on Kibana 7.17
When I try to customize my timestamp to aggregate data on several days, I can do it easily

[image]

However, when I try to aggregate my data on several weeks, months or years, it is greyed and reset to 1. I cannot aggregate for instance on 3 months to have a quarter.

[image]

The same problem appears on weeks, and years.

Is there some trick to change timestamp to 2,3 or 4 months (or weeks or years)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html#calendar_intervals) not possible for Elasticsearch to have a calendar_interval of multiple quantities. That is why Lens is disabling the field.

Instead of 3 months you may try using quarter to get an interval of one quarter.

Response copied from my post [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-lens-cannot-cutomize-timestamp-on-several-months-weeks-or-years/327156)